# Combining imports in development CSS into 1 file for production

Tags: css, optimization, sass, less

Is there something that I can use that will quickly merge multiple CSS imports into one CSS file.

For example, let's say I have a main styles.css file that has a large number of imports during development:

```
@import url('normalize.css');
@import url('1.css');
@import url('2.css');
...
@import url('10.css');
```

I separate them during development just for my own sanity.

I'd like to minimize HTTP requests during production though to 1 styles file, rather than 11, 12 , etc.

So, is there something, other than manually copy/pasting into one file, that can put these imports into 1 file?

Does LESS or SASS do something like this?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that minimizing HTTP requests is good, but caching is better. If the browser has `normalize.css` cached, it doesn't have to make a HTTP request. You might want to have one CSS file with styles that are used on every page and another with page specific styles. That way your subsequent pages can use the cached base styles and only download the few page specific ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LESS and SASS do this and more. There are many server-side ways to collate your css files into a single document (Less can do that with js too but I wouldn't recommend this as you would lose your styling with js off)

Yahoo YUI compressor / Rhino do the same if I am not mistaken: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/#work

if you check the global options, this one works for you:

-o outfile

```
  Place output in file outfile. If not specified, the YUI Compressor will
  default to the standard output, which you can redirect to a file.
  Supports a filter syntax for expressing the output pattern when there are
  multiple input files.  ex:
      java -jar yuicompressor.jar -o '.css$:-min.css' *.css
  ... will minify all .css files and save them as -min.css
```

Comment: Unfortunately, yui-compressor does *not* do that.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner could you elaborate more? I haven't used YUI compressor to concatenate files but the documentation seems pretty clear on this option.

Comment: Not sure if this renders correctly in a comment:

    ```$ cat test2.css 
    @import url(test.css);
    $ cat test.css 
    a {font-weight:heavy}
    $ yui-compressor test2.css 
    @ import url(test.css);```

This is version 2.4.7.

Answer (score 2):

css-compressor, which is based on yuicompressor does just that:

https://github.com/samilyak/css-compressor

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to use YUI Compressor is by downloading the binaries, which require
Java, and executing them on the command line:

java -jar yuicompressor-x.y.z.jar foo.js | foo.min.js

However, you can do this programmatically on deployment. If you’re using a library
like Sprockets or Less, they’ll do this for you. Otherwise, there are several interface
libraries to YUI Compressor, such as Sam Stephenson’s Ruby-YUI-compressor gem or
the Jammit library.

Comment: Unfortunately, yui-compressor does *not* inline @import’s.